# UnicodeDecodeError while trying to run collectstatic - Using Django

Tags: django, python-3.x, unicode, django-staticfiles

I'm getting a `UnicodeDecodeError` while trying to push my project to Heroku. I also get this error when I try to run `collectstatic` in my console. I have no idea what could be causing this. I'm still new, and I can't figure it out by reading through the traceback. I'm using `whitenoise` to store my static data. If you could help me troubleshoot as to what the problem may be, that would be awesome. Here is the traceback:

```
$ python manage.py collectstatic --noinput
remote:        Traceback (most recent call last):
remote:          File "manage.py", line 15, in <module>
remote:            execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
remote:          File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 371, in execute_from_command_line
remote:            utility.execute()
remote:          File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 365, in execute
remote:            self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
remote:          File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 288, in run_from_argv
remote:            self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
remote:          File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 335, in execute
remote:            output = self.handle(*args, **options)
remote:          File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/staticfiles/management/commands/collectstatic.py", line 189, in handle
remote:            collected = self.collect()
remote:          File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/staticfiles/management/commands/collectstatic.py", line 129, in collect
remote:            for original_path, processed_path, processed in processor:
remote:          File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/whitenoise/storage.py", line 67, in post_process
remote:            for name, hashed_name, processed in files:
remote:          File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/whitenoise/storage.py", line 29, in post_process_with_compression
remote:            for name, hashed_name, processed in files:
remote:          File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/staticfiles/storage.py", line 405, in post_process
remote:            yield from super().post_process(*args, **kwargs)
remote:          File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/staticfiles/storage.py", line 239, in post_process
remote:            for name, hashed_name, processed, _ in self._post_process(paths, adjustable_paths, hashed_files):
remote:          File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/staticfiles/storage.py", line 290, in _post_process
remote:            content = original_file.read().decode(settings.FILE_CHARSET)
remote:        UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xff in position 0: invalid start byte
remote:
remote:  !     Error while running '$ python manage.py collectstatic --noinput'.
```

Comment: Some file is being decoded with the wrong codec: the settings say UTF-8 should be used, but apparently the file was stored using a different codec (maybe UTF-16, since the first byte is `0xFF`). Unfortunately, the error message and traceback don't tell which file this is about. But you should definitely check the encoding of the static files.

Comment: Thank you for that. I ended up figuring out which file it was and changed.

Answer (score 0):

One of my CSS files was encoded differently. I just deleted files from my static\css folder until I found which one was causing the error, and changed it.